# Як правильно "розсадник" чи "розплідник"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів

При написані дипломної роботи про рослини, правильно було б вживати "розсадник декоративних рослин ...." але в Інтернет джерелах зустрічається обидва варіанти і "розсадник декоративних рослин" і "розплідник декоративних рослин".

Я знайшла в Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980) такі два визначення:

***Розплідник*** - це спеціалізоване племінне господарство для розмноження й вирощування тварин.

***Розсадник*** - 1.Спеціальний ящик із землею для вирощування розсади овочевих і кормових культур, а також декоративних рослин. 2. Місце, ділянка, де вирощують молоді рослини для пересадки.

Але викладач говорить, що також вживають "розплідник декоративних рослин", коли ми говоримо про черенкування рослини та вирощування плодових саджанців.

Яке словосполучення потрібно вжити при написані про вирощування троянд?

Comment: Без знання контексту, в якому ви хочете використовувати це слово, відповідь на ваше запитання стає тривіальною: якщо у контексті «господарство», то правильно — *«розплідник»*; якщо у контексті «ящик або ділянка», то правильно — *«розсадник»*; якщо у якомусь непрямому контексті, то вкажіть, в якому саме.

Comment: Можливо, це була спроба не запитати, а надати інформацію? Stack Exchange не забороняє це, а навіть, навпаки, заохочує. Але: (1) запитання в такому випадку має бути оформлене, як запитання; (2) під час створення запитання треба натиснути на галочку «Answer your own question» і ввести відповідь **в окремому полі**, що з'явиться ничже; (3) відповідь має містити, власне, відповідь (інформацію в тексті), а не бути набором посилань.

Comment: Якщо вже знайдена Вами інформація Вас влаштовує (Ви вважаєте її достатньою відповіддю на власне запитання), то Ви можете поділитися нею в полі «Post Your Answer», а якщо ні — то добре в самому запитанні зазаначити, мовляв, «я сама знайшла <оте>, але воно мені до кінця не допомогло, тому що <…>». Адже запитання має бути запитанням (таким текстом, щоб той, хто його читає і можливо схоче відповісти, чітко розумів, що саме Вам треба).

Comment: Дуже дякую за чудові зміни. Можна ще вточнити: Ви кажете про «вирощування троянд», але про що саме мова: ящик чи ціле господарство чи щось інше? І ще, коли Ви на початку пишете «правильно було б вживати „розсадник декоративних рослин“», то з якої саме позиції/причин Ви маєте на увазі, що так було би правильно?

Comment: Лише з визначення тлумачного словника "розсадник", я вважаю, що потрібно вживати "розсадник декоративних рослин". Говорячи про "вирощування троянд", мається на увазі ціле господарство, яке вирощує лише троянди, на відкритих ділянках та в контейнерах.

Answer (score 2):

Згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozplidnyk) - ми вживаємо слово "розплідник" у значенні "спеціалізоване племінне господарство для розмноження й вирощування тварин", і лише у переносному значенні ("місце зосередження або джерело чого-небудь") це слово буде синонімом до слова "розсадник", яке може мати таке ж переносне значення.
Таке ж визначення знаходимо у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Щодо слова "розсадник" - [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozsadnyk) дає таке сільськогосподарські визначення "місце, ділянка, де вирощують молоді рослини для пересадки" та "спеціальний ящик із землею для вирощування розсади овочевих і кормових культур, а також декоративних рослин". Згідно до інформації [цього сайту](https://studfiles.net/preview/4395263/page:16/), ми також бачимо, що розсадник призначений для вирощування рослин.

Отож, робимо висновок, що правильно казати "розсадник декоративних рослин", а не "розплідник декоративних рослин".